# best way to create settings for a google apps script deployed as web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to embed a Google Apps Script in my Google Sites. So I need to develop it as a web app. I want it to have some settings (specifically, a key to a spreadsheet to use as backend). This is not something that is managed by the users of the script, rather by the one embedding the script (me, but maybe others sometime). What is the best way of doing that? Also, while developing the script there's the deployment link where it can be used directly. How can I have the setting there?

Comment: You can embed a script directly into a Google site, without making it a web app. Can you give us more information about what your deployment scenario is, to explain why you feel a web app is needed?

Comment: I thought this is the way. I created the script through Manage site -> Apps Scripts. Basically I want a page with a simple form that will be loadable by a mobile phone (maybe I don't even require the site, if there's an easy way to use the form directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to store a key, and then change that key periodically should you wish to do so (Or allow a function by which others can change the key).

To answer your second question, the deployment link is not for embedding. Do not use it to embed a gadget in your site, otherwise the tiniest change while updating your script could render the whole thing completely unusable while you update it.Instead, deploy the script as the web app and post the [deployed version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) to your site.